# Why does Python's subprocess call not work correctly with sh on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, escaping

The following code prints `hi`:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['sh', '-c', ' "$@" ', '-', 'echo', 'hi'])
```

However, on native Windows Python, a slight modification of the code:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['sh', '-c',  '"$@"' , '-', 'echo', 'hi'])
```

produces the following errors:

```
sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Why is this?

Comment: probably, yes. Because I've worked years with subprocess & quoting & windows and never stumbled on that bug.

Comment: most of the time when it contains quotes it's a mistake from thje caller who adds them when they're not needed. I agree windows command line is horrible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be a **surprisingly long-standing bug** in MSYS2 (likely from Cygwin), caused by Windows's [idiosyncratic](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/twistylittlepassagesallalike/2011/04/23/everyone-quotes-command-line-arguments-the-wrong-way/) [quoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//17w5ykft(v=vs.85)) [rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-commandlinetoargvw).
What happens is that MSYS2 expects

```
subprocess.list2cmdline(['sh', '-c',  '"$@"' , '-', 'echo', 'hi'])
```

to translate to

```
sh -c "\"$@\"" - echo hi
```

but in fact it produces the following:

```
sh -c \"$@\" - echo hi
```

It's difficult to fathom why this is the case, until you realize that MSYS2 thinks that Windows command line quoting rules are such that backslashes are treated as *literals* outside of double-quotes.
So what ends up happening is that `\"$@\"` gets interpreted as a single literal backslash, followed by the quoted string `$@\"`, whose ending quote is **missing**. If we added the ending quote, it would in fact look like `\"$@\""`, which *seems* unbalanced, but is in fact balanced to MSYS2. (!)
When the argument contains a space, however, the whole thing gets naively quoted,  accidentally masking the issue.

Why does it interpret things this way? It's probably because of the documentation, which [says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-commandlinetoargvw):

> `CommandLineToArgvW` has a special interpretation of backslash characters when they are followed by a quotation mark character (`"`). This interpretation assumes that any preceding argument is a valid file system path, or else it may behave unpredictably.
>
> This special interpretation controls the **"in quotes" mode** tracked by the parser.

It's quite easy and tempting to misread this and think that backslashes lose their special meaning when the parser is **not** in "in-quotes" mode, and that's what the MSYS2 parser says. However, if you read the next two sentences carefully, it explains what precisely *"in-quotes" mode* means:

> When this mode is off, whitespace terminates the current argument. When on, whitespace is added to the argument like all other characters.

That is *all*. Backslashes *don't* suddenly become verbatim outside quotes. They can still escape a quote just like they would inside, except of course the rules are even *more* complicated inside than outside.

How do you work around this? Thankfully native Windows Python allows passing the entire command line as a single string literal, so you can in fact work around this bug using a helper method:

```
import subprocess
def list2cmdline(args): return ' '.join(map(
    lambda a: a if a.lstrip().startswith('"') or '"' not in a else '"' + a + '"',
    map(lambda a: subprocess.list2cmdline([a]), args)))

subprocess.call(list2cmdline(['sh', '-c', '"$@"', '-', 'echo', 'hi']))
```

Alternatively, you can monkeypatch it directly:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.list2cmdline = (lambda old: lambda args: ' '.join(map(
    lambda a: a if a.lstrip().startswith('"') or '"' not in a else '"' + a + '"',
    map(lambda a: old([a]), args))))(subprocess.list2cmdline)

subprocess.call(['sh', '-c', '"$@"', '-', 'echo', 'hi'])
```

This shouldn't affect any correctly-behaving programs, because there are multiple ways to quote things, but it should fix the issue with MSYS2.

Comment: morality: never use "sh" in windows. It only leads to issues with backslashes/slashes, carriage returns, paths with drives.. Note that subprocess shouldn't even escape the quotes with backslash _on windows_ because backslash means nothing for windows. By using "sh" you're "cheating" native python by virtually changing the OS

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Actually that's quite wrong. This has nothing to do with `sh`, I was just using that as a demo. Backslashes *do* mean something on native Windows; they affect how a single string is parsed into `argv`. That's what I was trying to explain here; backslashes mean something if and only if you've opened a double-quote. You can see this if you call any other program. In fact if I get the chance I'll just call Python again to demonstrate that it has nothing to do with `sh`.

Comment: it has nothing to do with sh of course. but your example uses it. If you have references for the backslash part, I'd be interested to read it because for me backslash is just the native windows path separator

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Oops, I have to retract part of what I said. It seems we're both partly right and partly wrong. I just tested this with another program, and you're right, Python's implementation is not buggy. The bug seems to be in MSYS2/Cygwin -- not specific to `sh`, but to the whole emulation layer in general. The description I gave seems to be how the layer interprets it, rather than the actual correct rules. However, I think the cause of this is a confusing quote in the documentation, that's easy to misinterpret to mean what I said. I'll explain it in my answer.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Regarding the fact that backslashes mean something though -- [it's straight from the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-commandlinetoargvw): *"`CommandLineToArgvW` has a special interpretation of backslash characters when they are followed by a quotation mark character (")."*

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Updated; see my answer.

Comment: IIRC from past problems, Cygwin/MSYS dosn't follow VC++ argument parsing. It approximates POSIX rules, including support for single-quote literal quoting. Even some of Microsoft's own command-line utilities implement custom argument parsing, plus of course the CMD shell. The only mandatory parsing rules are for quoting and whitespace in `CreateProcessW` in order to parse the executable from `lpCommandLine` when `lpApplicationName` is omitted. Beyond that, VC++ `argv` parsing is the most common, so that's all `subprocess.list2cmdline` will ever support.